# Best way to create a link between two different types of users?

Tags: relations, data-display

**Background:**

We have two different users: Customers and Service Providers.

Now Customers can have Service Providers and naturally, Service Providers will have Customers.

Now the Admin has the ability to create a link between Customers and Service Providers.

**Problem:**

I am a bit confused whether I need to create the ability to link both ways: meaning, Customers dashboard will have a "Link to Service Providers" button and vice versa, Service Providers dashboard will have a "Link to Customers".

That, versus, just creating from one side since the other side will automatically be linked anyway.

Which is better and more common?

Comment: I'd add both. Though, there needs to be a cue or such showing that it has been done already or something that shows the customer/s or service providers.

Answer (score 1):

If the admin has the ability to create the link, have a separate module (maybe in a tab or as a link) that allows him/her to link Customers and Service Providers.

The link would trigger a separate page/module/modal which allows this process to be carried forward. It would also eliminate the problem of consistency and updation each Dashboard